# Find AD security groups on network folders

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am not a programmer, I must of taken a wrong turn! So that's out of the way, how on earth is there not an easy way to take a set of network folders and pipe out a list of AD security groups that are applied to it? I have googled my butt off but there are a million similar questions and i have tested a few scripts but cant get exactly what i want or a lot of errors. We have a top level directory of about 7 folders and security is about 3 levels deep. We want to cleanup unused or orphaned security groups out of AD TOOLS, and try to get a feel of what is used and what is not. Attempting a "Network drive cleanup" at my Organization.
What is the best way to accomplish this? I tried this in PS

```
Get-ChildItem "\\wfs.company.ca\adv\workgroups\adv services" -recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName} | Export-CSV C:\"adv services".csv
```

It worked but gave me too much info and not specific Group names.

and i also tried something like this which just produced errors.

```
# Scope options are Universal, DomainLocal,Global
# Get-GroupMember -Scope DomainLocal

Function Get-GroupMember{
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $scope
    )
    $Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupScope -eq $scope -and Members -ne "NULL"} -Properties Name | 
                  Select-Object Name, @{Name="GroupMembers";Expression={(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$_" | 
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName) -join "`n"}}
}
        $Groups | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
        $Groups | Out-GridView
        $Groups | Export-Csv C:\groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I dont mind putting in the work and research i just dont know where to start.
Any pointers much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get a unique list of applied identities (groups and users):

```
(Get-ChildItem "\\wfs.company.ca\adv\workgroups\adv services" -Recurse | Get-Acl).Access.IdentityReference | select -Unique
```

Furthermore, you could use `Get-ADGroup` or other ways to check if it's a group or user.